# My jQuery Carousel stopped working

Tags: jquery, carousel

I have my own jQuery carousel, suddenly it stopped working on Xmas eve and I have no clue why. The basic semantic structure is simple:

```
<section class = "slideshow">
   <div id = "slides">
      <ul>
          <li id = "slide_1">
             <div class = "slide">
                 <div >
                     content for slide 1
                  </div>                 
             </div>
          </li>
          <li>
             <div class = "slide">
                 <div >
                     content for slide 2
                 </div>                 
             </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</section>
<input type = "button" value = ">>" id = "forward"/>​
```

The corresponding jQuery is :

```
$('#forward').click(slideup);

function slideup()
{

 var item_width = $('#slides li').outerWidth(true);
 var old_left = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left'));
 var left_indent = old_left - item_width;

 $('#slides ul').animate({'left':left_indent},"slow", function(){      
   $('#slides li:last').after($('#slides li:first'));
       $('#slides ul').css({'left':0});
   } ); 
}
```

But nothing is happening. Here is a js fiddle that captures the CSS as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/bbCab/8/

​Thanks!

P.S: Merry Xmas Stackoverflowers :)

Comment: I'd suggest that as it's so simple and it stopped after it had been working I reckon you have a link to google cdn for the jquery source and an update has broken your code

Comment: oh ...so how do I resolve this ?

Comment: AWS went down on xmas eve. Where were you hosting the script?

Comment: its on my local machine right now, I don't suppose it has anything to do with google update or AWS going down

Comment: old_left is coming up as NaN because the actual value is "auto".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to animate margin-left:

```
$('#slides ul').animate({'left':left_indent},"slow", function(){
```

to

```
$('#slides ul').animate({'margin-left':left_indent},"slow", function(){
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/bbCab/16/